# How to encode video?

Tags: c#, c++, c, video-encoding

I want to write a video encoding.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Start by studying the JPEG spec, and still image encoding in general. Move on once you've mastered that. Unless you have an absolutely revolutionary idea, you'll be much better off writing an encoder for an existing encoding. (Then, you will be successful even if you have a merely ingenious new approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean implement / invent a codec, or do you mean encode a video?

For encoding a video, use libavcodec from ffmpeg.

For implementing or developing a new codec, this is typically done over a series of years by a team of experts, and if you have to ask this general a question it may be a learning experience but would most likely be a waste of your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), then just call the executable from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). it has an easy to use wrapper around one of the native API's in windows for doing this and also around ffmpeg.